# Builder of type Builder? How to translate that to kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, log4j2

I am about to port some java code to kotlin. I just found some awkward factory method, which looks pretty straight forward to transform:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SyslogAppender;

public class Test {

    public Appender getSyslogAppender(String id, String host, int port, boolean immediateFlush, boolean newLine) {
        return SyslogAppender.newSyslogAppenderBuilder()
                .setId(id)
                .setNewLine(newLine)
                .withHost(host)
                .withPort(port)
                .withImmediateFlush(immediateFlush)
                .build();
    }
}
```

So my first try was:

```
fun getSyslogAppender(id: String, host: String, port: Int, immediateFlush: Boolean, newLine: Boolean): Appender {
    return SyslogAppender.newSyslogAppenderBuilder()
            .setId(id)
            .setNewLine(newLine)
            .withHost(host)
            .withPort(port)
            .withImmediateFlush(immediateFlush)
            .build()
}
```

But the kotlin compiler was not happy. It seemed uncertain what type should be returned:

```
Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter B in fun <b : syslogappender.builder!> newSyslogAppenderBuilder(): B! Please specify it explicitly.
```

Ok, lets give it a type:

```
SyslogAppender.newSyslogAppenderBuilder<SyslogAppender.Builder>()
```

But wait:

```
One type argument expected for class Builder<b : syslogappender.builder!> : Builder, SocketAppender.AbstractBuilder defined in org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SyslogAppender
```

Lets look at the definition:

```
public class SyslogAppender extends SocketAppender {
    public static class Builder<B extends Builder<B>> extends AbstractBuilder<B>
        implements org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Builder<SocketAppender>
```

What??? A Builder of type B. Where B has the super type Builder of B? ... Some ours of thinking and experimenting later ... I don't get it.

Does anybody know how to solve that? I am sure its something totally simple.

Comment: I'm not sure, but could you try `SyslogAppender.newSyslogAppenderBuilder<SyslogAppender.Builder<*>>()`?

Comment: This results in: 
     Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'SyslogAppender.Builder<syslogappender.builder!>!'

Comment: @FrankWeinhold post your kotlin code which produces the given error, pls